# Почему записывает пустую строку в первый элемент массива?

Tags: c, массивы, строки, работа-с-текстом

```
char text[20][81];
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) 
{
        gets_s(text[i]);
}
```

Как только начинает выполняться цикл, gets_s() записывает в text[0] пустую строку "", и только потом начинает записывать в text[i] строки с консоли.

В чём может быть причина такого поведения?

Answer (score 1):

Да как обычно - считали что-то типа числа, а строку до конца не сбросили...

Добавьте перед циклом

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

(из тегов непонятно, на C вы пишете, или на C++).

Comment: По правилам курса, который сейчас идёт в университете, я пишу на Си, но среду разработки использую VS. И библиотеки подключаю Си-шные (".h"). При добавлении данной строчки в код, вылезают ошибки о том, что он не знает таких имён и в namespace std вообще их нет. Есть аналог данной строки для Си?